# Azure Active Directory Account Lockout Threshold

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there a way to change the Account Lockout Threshold for an account in Azure Active Directory?  This would normally be a Group Policy change however I understand Azure does not support Group Policy.  Azure Active Directory seems to lock users out after 10 failed attempts however I have a requirement to lock them out after 6.

The documentation I could find on this (here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj943764.aspx) states that:

> After 10 unsuccessful logon attempts (wrong password), the user will
>   need to solve a CAPTCHA dialog as part of logon.
>
> After a further 10 unsuccessful logon attempts (wrong password) and
>   correct solving of the CAPTCHA dialog, the user will be locked out for
>   a time period. Further incorrect passwords will result in an
>   exponential increase in the lockout time period.

But doesn't state if this can be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**As of now there is no way for configure lock out parameter**".This is the official communication i have received from MS. let's see when they will avail this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this may be an option now days if you pay for Azure AD Premium. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-pass-through-authentication-smart-lockout).